Why do comments also show up when you want to edit a post?
Why do comments under a post show up when you want to edit that post?

I know they should show up for moderators to review suggested edits. But why should the one who wants to edit also see the comments?

i mean, they were already there, along with all the other answers, why should they go away? editing doesn't send you to a new page

@KevinB But the comments are irrelevant when you want to edit a question or an answer. Most edits are done to correct grammars, typos, punctuations, tags, and the sentences used. I first wanted to ask this question with feature-request tag. But I chose support instead. Maybe I change my mind again.

Comments are intended to seek clarification on a post, if an edit-writer wants to ensure they've addressed any comments, they would need to see those comments, on top of: they're already shown, it would be extra work to hide them, and there's no good reason to do that. Don't bother making this a feature request, it makes no sense and has no justification.

the comments don't matter, you see them because you're editing a post inline... you also get to see the site header and site footer.

Because it was a requested feature: On the <2k edit page, can we please see the comments on our post?. As to the reasons why, see the feature request post.

@KevinB For users without the privilege to make binding edits to all posts, editing sends them to a separate page, even when editing a post they can edit bindingly (own post or community wiki post).

"But the comments are irrelevant when you want to edit a question or an answer" then don't look at them. Is it really a problem that they show up?
